# Newbie learning how to properly use an IoC with wpf, mvvm, and tracking a CurrentView Property for use with DataTemplates

Tags: wpf, mvvm, view, autofac

I'm trying to learn how to use Autofac properly with interfaces with wpf, and a mvvm scenario and bind a contentcontrol sitting on my mainWindow to a 'CurrentView' property off a mainViewModel, but I don't know whether I should do this with concrete BaseViewModel classes, or if I should have CurrentView property as an interface ? And I would like to set the CurrentView property in my MainWindowViewModel constructor.

simple locator:

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    public IContainer Container { get; set; }

    public IMainWindowViewModel MainWindowViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return Container.Resolve<IMainWindowViewModel>(); 
        }
    }

    public IOtherPageViewModel OtherPageViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return Container.Resolve<IOtherPageViewModel >();
        }
    }
}
```

Sitting in my MainWindow.xaml

```
 <ContentControl 
    Content="{Binding Path=CurrentView}"
    Grid.Row="0"  
    VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" >
</ContentControl>
```

MainWindowViewModel  *** Here is my concern, should baseViewModel not be a concrete, and I should implement an interface here, or whats the proper way to set the currentView when you need to show different views, for multiple viewModels? I ask because I'd like to have Autofac inject my currentview here in the MainWindowViewModel constructor. Is this possible?

```
 private baseViewModel currentView;
    public baseViewModel CurrentView
    {
        get
        {
            return currentView;
        }
        set
        {
            currentView = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.CurrentView);
        }
    }
```

In the past I've used baseViewModels and then datatemplates on the view but I don't know if thats a sound implementation

Comment: So I went the route of instead of baseViewModel, injecting a IBaseInterface into the MainViewModel constructor with Autofac and setting the CurrentView that way. Then using a DataTemplate in the xaml for the view switching. Is this implementation okay?

Comment: If you're [using MVVM then you really should be using an MVVM framework](http://www.lhotka.net/weblog/UsingTheMVVMPatternRequiresAFramework.aspx). I would recommend [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/), which makes view composition incredibly easy.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into Caliburn. That's probably a better way to go